# Search Query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I am new in codeigniter. I want to create a search bar where user write some keyword and it will check in all fields of table in database and then show relative result.

**Here is my code of View:**

```
<?php

    echo '<h2>Search Books</h2>';
    echo form_open('site/search');?>

<p>
<label for="title"> Title:</label>
 <input type="text"  placeholder="Search" name="search" size="50%">
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

<!--Here will be Search Result-->
<?php if (isset($searches)): foreach($searches as $search):?>
<h4><?php echo " &nbsp ";
echo $search->book_name;
echo " &nbsp "; ?></h4>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
No Book Found
<?php endif;?>
```

**And the controller code with name site is**

```
function search(){

            $search_book = array (
                            $search= $this->input->post('search')
            );
            $this->users_model->user_search($search_book);
            $this->dashboard();
```

**Query Result in Controller**

```
if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search())
            {

                $search['searches'] = $query;
            }
            $data = $search;
             $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
```

**Here is Model Code:**

```
function user_search($search_book){

                 $query = $this->db->like('book_name', $search_book);
             $this->db->or_like('author', $search_book);
              $this->db->or_like('date', $search_book);
             $this->db->get('books');
                return $query->result();
```

**Error Shown**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Missing argument 1 for Users_model::user_search(), called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Pure_Logics\application\controllers\site.php on line
>   28 and defined
>
> Filename: models/users_model.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Pure_Logics\application\models\users_model.php
>   Line: 26 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Pure_Logics\application\controllers\site.php
>   Line: 28 Function: user_search
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Pure_Logics\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: $this->users_model->user_search()  missing argument

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Missing argument in method calling

```
$this->users_model->user_search()
```

change to

```
 if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search($this->input->post('search')))
  {

     $search['searches'] = $query;
  }
```

**Model:**

```
function user_search($search_book){

                 $this->db->like('book_name', $search_book);
                 $this->db->or_like('author', $search_book);
                 $this->db->or_like('date', $search_book);
                 $query = $this->db->get('books');
                 return $query->result();
  }
```

**Controller:**

```
function search(){

    $this->dashboard();
     $data['searches'] =array();
    if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search($this->input->post('search')))
    {

        $data['searches'] = $query;
    }

     $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);

}
```

1) You calling method without argument . But your defined method with argument in model .

Comment: Which argument i miss? I didn't understand

Comment: Dear I dont know which argument i can pass? Please help me and tell me which argument will pass here?

Comment: Now it show me another error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pure_Logics\application\models\users_model.php on line 32`

Comment: Thanks Brother :)

Comment: glad to help you @sunny

Answer (score 1):

In your Query Result in Controller you don't pass argument to `user_search()` :

```
if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search())
```

You must be send an argument to it like below:

```
if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search($search_query))
```

Comment: You need to send argument to it like: `if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search($this->input->post('search')))`

Answer (score 1):

> select data using multiple conditions and search keyword

```
 function select_data_by_search($tablename, $search_condition, $condition_array = array(), $data = '*', $sortby = '', $orderby = '', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str = array()) {
    $this->db->select($data);
    if (!empty($join_str)) {
        foreach ($join_str as $join) {
            $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id']);
        }
    }
    $this->db->where($condition_array);
    $this->db->where($search_condition);

    //Setting Limit for Paging
    if ($limit != '' && $offset == 0) {
        $this->db->limit($limit);
    } else if ($limit != '' && $offset != 0) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }
    //order by query
    if ($sortby != '' && $orderby != '') {
        $this->db->order_by($sortby, $orderby);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get($tablename);
    //if limit is empty then returns total count
    if ($limit == '') {
        $query->num_rows();
    }
    //if limit is not empty then return result array
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

> Description of function passed parameter
>       $tablename="tablename";
>       $search_condition="pass search sting";
>       $condition_array="pass you multiple where condition in array like :- array("con1"=>"value","con2"=>"value")";
>       $data = 'selcte data name like :- user.name,user.email'
>       $sortby="sortby value";
>       $orderby="orderby value";
>       $limi="limit value";
>       $offset="";
>           $join_str[0]['table'] = 'table1';
>           $join_str[0]['join_table_id'] = 'table1.id';
>           $join_str[0]['from_table_id'] = 'maintable.id';
>           $join_str[0]['join_type'] = 'left';

```
     $join_str[1]['table'] = 'table1';   
    $join_str[1]['join_table_id'] = 'table1.id';   
    $join_str[1]['from_table_id'] = 'maintable.id';   
    $join_str[1]['join_type'] = 'left';
```

Comment: you can use this function for all module as  common search function

Answer (score 1):

In your **Controller**: array format was incorrect

```
function search(){
                $search_book = array (
                      'search' => $this->input->post('search')
                );
                $this->users_model->user_search($search_book);
                $this->dashboard();
```

**Query Result in Controller**

```
if ($query = $this->users_model->user_search($search_book))
   {
       $search['searches'] = $query;
   }
$data = $search;
$this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
```

**Model Code:**

```
function user_search($search_book)
{
   return $this->db->like('book_name', $search_book);
                     ->or_like('author', $search_book);
                     ->or_like('date', $search_book);
                     ->get('books')->result();
```